# Improper positioning when plotting adjacency matrix - R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to plot the adjacency matrix of a graph like a chessboard (black for 1s, white for 0s, or viceversa)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

Using the following code:

```
require(igraph)
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

g <- make_star(5)
gAdjMatrix <- as.matrix(as_adj(g))

print(gAdjMatrix)

logMatrix <- (gAdjMatrix == 1)
logMatrix

mm <- logMatrix

mm %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value, 
                color = value)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("white", "black")) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
  guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

I'm getting this output:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should return what you are looking for:

```
mm %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value, 
                color = value)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "black", "FALSE" = "white")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "white", "FALSE" = "black")) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: plot]

Explanation:

1. It's generally safer to use named vectors with `scale_XX_manual`, to ensure that you map the correct values;
2. By default, a plot's origin is at the bottom left corner, not the top left corner. If you want it to start at the top, reverse your y-axis.

Side note: You can minimize such problems in the future, by leaving out appearance-related code until you've finished tweaking the more important aspects of your plot. Had you left the axis & legend labels in the plot, the above issues could have been easier to spot:

```
mm %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value, 
                color = value)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("white", "black")) +
  theme_bw() #+
  # theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
  #       axis.text = element_blank(),
  #       axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  #       panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
  # guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) + 
  # scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  # scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 1):

First, matrix index and rectangular coordinate are different. I make a matrix such like :

```
> x <- matrix(c(1, rep(0, 8)), 3, 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

You can see that index `[1, 1]` is `1`. It is located in the top left of the matrix. But when I plot this matrix with `image()`, the value `1` is located in the button left :

[image]

This is because matrix index system's `[1, 1]` and rectangular coordinate system's `(1, 1)` are not the same position.

To make the transformation from matrix index to rectangular coordinate, you can try:

```
y <- t(x)[ , ncol(x):1]
image(y)
```

[image]

You succeed in presenting the matrix to a heatmap with the same position.

---

So, with your data, you can transform it to rectangular coordinate first and plot it :

```
mm2 <- t(mm)[ , ncol(mm):1]

mm2 %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2)) + # Don't exchange Var1 and Var2 here
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value, 
                color = value)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "black", "FALSE" = "white")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "white", "FALSE" = "black")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]